# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models' for example keras_ssd7

Tags: import, model

I am learning SSD on Google Co lab. I am trying to import all the pakages but I have faced an error in line 9. Please see am attachment and eeror occured in below code:

```
from models.keras_ssd7 import build_model
```

I shall be thankful for suggestions!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMDoM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you probably cloned the repository stored here: https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/ssd_keras.git like I just did.

The problem is that in this repository, there is a directory "models" with file keras_ssd7.py that imports packages directly from Keras like this:

```
from keras.models import Model
```

Each of these needs to be updated to read:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

Note: If you are actually using this repository, there are several directories that need to be updated in this same manner.